# Why should people aim for moksha and god realisation rather than occult powers?

Tags: tantra, bhakti, services

Realised beings like Ramakrishna paramahamsa have always advocated for god realisation and have criticised occult powers as they tend to remove the focus from god realisation. Why should one aim for god realisation, in the first place ? Also , if tantrik practices are used for good then why not tantra is as popular as Bhakti Marga in Upasana ? Also if we are aiming from liberation , then , are we not , making a cowardly attempt to think about the betterment and happiness for only ourselves and not country or nation or masses of people those who are poor or in want of help. We should use tantrik ways to help ourselves and think for the betterment of the society rather than aiming for our own salvation ?

Comment: Where can I learn occult powers ? I think real occult powers come to only those people who have realised god. Otherwise bad people would have gotten occult powers and used it to win over the world. But we don't hear things like someone winning the world, using occult powers.

Comment: @river Nope. In Tantra Sāstras and Puranas Even Sadhana of lower beings like bhutas, pisāchas , Yaksinis etc. are known to grant occult powers. One doesn't need to be God-realized to get them

Comment: Of course, you won't see any Tom , Dick or Harry with occult powers because the Sādhana isn't everyone's cup of tea! The Sādhana of these beings is extremely risky and dangerous.

Comment: @Asoka But Why people who have occult powers not use them to win over the world or become extremely rich ?

Comment: @river Like  There are hardly any who have them in the current yuga in the first place